# Change product item HTML?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've looked throught almost every single file in woocommerce directory but everything is very modular (as a modern code should be). I cannot figure out how to change the `HTML` of single product item (do not confuse with product page).

*E.g* shortcode `[recent_products per_page="3"]` generated something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
            <img>
            <h3></h3>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            <img>
            <h3></h3>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            <img>
            <h3></h3>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could any WooCommerce developer lend me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that html structure is created by 3 template files... `loop\loop-start.php`, `loop\loop-end.php`, and `content-product.php`. Look for these files on the templates folder of woocommerce plugin folder.

you need to override these templates file.. instructions here: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1)...